# Precise definition of a scheme (Key question: How to define an open subfunctor without resorting to classical scheme theory)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory

### Speculation and background

Let $\mathcal{C}:=\mathrm{CRing}^\text{op}_\text{Zariski}$, the affine Zariski site.  Consider the category of sheaves, $\operatorname{Sh}(\mathcal{C})$.

According to [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/scheme#translation_between_the_two_approaches), schemes are those sheaves that "have a cover by Zariski-open immersions of affine schemes in the category of presheaves over Aff."

In SGA 4.1.ii.5 Grothendieck defines a further topology on $\operatorname{Sh}(\mathcal{C})$ using a "familles couvrantes", which are families of morphisms $\{U_i \to X\}$ such that the induced map $\coprod U_i \to X$ is an epimorphism.  Further, he gives another definition.  A family of morphisms $\{U_i \to X\}$ is called "bicouvrante" if it is a "famille couvrante" and the map $\coprod U_i \to \coprod U_i \times_X \coprod U_i$ is an epimorphism. [Note: This is given for a *general* category of sheaves on a site, not sheaves on our affine Zariski site.]

Speculation: I assume that the nLab definition means that we have a (bi)covering family of open immersions of representables, but as it stands, we do not have a sufficiently good definition of an open immersion, or equivalently, open subfunctor.

It seems like the notion of a bicovering family is very important, because this is precisely the condition we require on algebraic spaces (if we replace our covering morphisms with etale surjective morphisms in a smart way and require that our cover be comprised of representables).

### Questions

What does "open immersion" mean precisely in categorical langauge?  How do we define a scheme *precisely* in our language of sheaves and grothendieck topologies?  Preferably, this answer should not depend on our base site.  The notion of an open immersion should be a notion that we have in any category of sheaves on any site.

Eisenbud and Harris fail to answer this question for the following reason: they rely on classical scheme theory for their definition of an open subfunctor (same thing as an open immersion).  If we wish to construct our theory of schemes with no logical prerequisites, this is circular.

Once we have this definition, do we require our covering family of open immersions to be a "covering family" or a "bicovering family"?

Further, how can we exhibit, in precise functor of points language, the definition of an algebraic space?

This last question should be a natural consequence of the previous questions provided they are answered in sufficient generality.

Comment: I have found _a_ definition of an open subfunctor, but it is still not sufficient.  In Gabriel-Demazure, an open subfunctor U of X is defined as a subfunctor of U such that every map from a representable functor f:specA -> X, f^-1(U) can be defined by an ideal in A.

Comment: Meanwhile, the topology I cited from SGA is still useful here, as it restricts to the canonical topology of "universally strict epimorphisms" on the category of sheaves that Grothendieck defines in 4.1.ii.2.5.  This is useful because it gives us an explicit characterization of coverings.  The only thing left to tie up all of the loose ends is decide whether our covers need be covers or bicovers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the paper of Kontsevich-Rosenberg [noncommutative space.](http://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/preprints/send?bid=2331), they defined formally open immersion and open immersion completely functorial way. This definition is nothing to do with "noncommutative"

Definition:
Formally open immersion is formally smooth monomorphism.

But one thing need to point out, they are working on Q-category which is a generalization of Grothendieck topologies(destination is dealing with topology without base change property).But just disregard this notion and work in usual grothendieck topology as you want

Answer (score 18):

I'm not sure if this will satisfy you, but a map of schemes is an open immersion if and only if it is an etale monomorphism. Etale means, by definition, formally etale and locally of finite presentation, both of which conditions have simple formulations in terms of functors of points, from Rings to Sets. Likewise, a map of schemes is a monomorphism if and only if the map of underlying functors is a monomorphism.

Comment: Yes! This is the answer I was looking for. I thought that etale (at least for rings) means finitely presented (as an algebra) + formally etale. That's why my lecture notes from commutative algebra say, anyway.

Comment: etale monomorphism is equivalent to smooth monomorphism

Comment: Actually, a morphism of sheaves can be formally &eacute;tale and locally of finite presentation without being representable by algebraic spaces.  One needs some kind of algebraizability hypothesis.

Comment: @Jonathan Wise: I think he's talking about representability by affines.  That is, we can define a "covering family" as a family of morphisms `$\{U_i\to X\}$` where all of the U_i are affine, and all of the morphisms are etale monic.  Then if we also require that this family is a "famille (bi?)couvrante", we should meet the requirements for the sheaf to be a scheme.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Jonathan: I hope I didn't suggest otherwise. Does that matter? But now that you mention it, it would be nice to see an example!

Comment: @James: I looked this up (now that you gave me a hint of what to look for), and there's a theorem in Stacks-GIT that a morphism is an open immersion if and only if it is etale and radiciel (universally injective).  Did you make a mistake, or is this case easier because it's all about affines?

Comment: I don't think I made a mistake. I'm pretty sure every thing I wrote is correct, and I'm not even sure what suggests that something might not be. But I guess I didn't really understand the original question, and so maybe I missed your point (which is why I said I wasn't sure if my answer would satisfy you).

Comment: No, no. I mean, there's a proof in Stacks-GIT that says: "A morphisms of schemes is an open immersion if and only if it is etale and radiciel". Although, this may be equivalent to mono for sheaves, which is something I didn't consider.  Meanwhile, I was reading your conversation on SBS about teachg AG by functors of points from the start.  I'm glad that we agree!

Comment: Haha! Your post here literally outlines the program I was interested in: http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/08/06/algebraic-geometry-without-prime-ideals/#comment-6354  Have you developed it any further than a comment on a blog post in that time?

Comment: No, not really. Someone should, though.

Comment: A long delayed response to Jim: the original question seemed to ask for an explanation of open subfunctors without reference to a notion of representability.  I didn't mean to suggest that you'd said something wrong---just that what you described can define open subsets of things that are already known to be geometric.  Artin's criteria allow you go the rest of the way.

There's an example where algebraization (and therefore representability) fails here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20863/is-the-functor-of-open-subschemes-representable

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a little trouble teasing out exactly what your question is, so I'll just write some things about sheaves that seem related and hope they are helpful.

Suppose $C$ is a site.  Let $\hat{C}$ be its category of presheaves and $\tilde{C}$ its category of sheaves.  The topology defined in SGA 4, II.5 is on $\hat{C}$, not on $\tilde{C}$ as you suggest in your question.  Its purpose is to give a topology on $\hat{C}$ such that the category of sheaves on $\hat{C}$ (that is, contravariant functors satisfying descent on the category of contravariant functors on $C$) should coincide with the category of sheaves on $C$ (i.e., $\tilde{\hat{C}} = \tilde{C}$).

You've got the condition for being bicovering backwards: a map of presheaves $H \rightarrow G$ is called bicovering if it is covering (with respect to the topology on $C$) and its diagonal $H \rightarrow H \times_G H$ is also covering.  (What it means for a map of sheaves to be covering is that for any map $X \rightarrow G$ with $X$ representable, the sieve of $X$ induced by $H \times_G X$ should be covering.)

A Grothendieck topology on $C$ is described by asking certain *subfunctors* (sieves) of objects of $C$ to be covering.  If $H$ is a subfunctor of $G$ then the relative diagonal map is automatically an epimorphism since it is an isomorphism (by definition).  The covering sieves of $X$ are the subfunctors of $X$ that become isomorphic to $X$ upon passing to associated sheaves.

The bicovering business arises when one wants to study which arbitrary morphisms of presheaves (not just inclusions) become isomorphisms upon passing to associated sheaves.  The notion of a covering morphism of presheaves explains which morphisms become surjections of sheaves.  The question then remains: which morphisms become injections?  A map of sheaves is an injection if and only if its relative diagonal is a surjection, so the condition is that the relative diagonal be a covering map.

Comment: Aha!  That is an interesting question.  However, I think you also misunderstood me.  What I meant to show was that a bicovering map of sheaves is the same thing as an isomorphism of sheaves.  So I don't think that worrying about bicoverings will help with what you want to do.

Comment: Then what more do we need, given a _sheaf_ in the Zariski topology (satisfies all descent stuff) for it to be a scheme?  I was under the impression that we need a "covering", that is, an epimorphism, that is constructed as the coproduct of a family of monomorphisms (an _open_ covering map).  

Comment: Eisenbud and Harris describe this indirectly.  I'm curious about how to represent it using topologies etc.

Comment: The problem in E&H is that they characterize schemes among sheaves by using this nasty concept of an open immersion, which relies on a classical notion of an open subscheme to define an open subfunctor.  

Comment: So, and you are looking for a purely categorical description of "open subfunctor"? I don't really understand what is going on there but perhaps you should take a look at "Categories of commutative algebras" by Diers. I chapter 4 he shows that open immersions of affine schemes correspond to so-called "singular epimorphisms". But this might just work in special cases, I don't know, too much stuff in there...

Comment: If you post it as an answer, I'll vote it up, Arminius.

Comment: Hehe. But I won't post it as an answer because I don't really understand that and if it really works in general (at least for schemes). The question still is if this also works for other geometrical objects. I have no idea! If you find out and post the answer here, I'll vote it up :)

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand\Aff{\mathrm{Aff}}\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}\newcommand\Sh{\mathrm{Sh}}$A morphism of sheaves $f: X \to Y$ in the fpqc topology on $\Aff$ [covers are *finite* universally epimorphic families $(\Spec(R_i)\to \Spec(R))_i$ in $\Aff$ with each morphism $\Spec(R_i)\to \Spec(R)$ flat] is representable by open immersions of schemes if and only if:

1. for all local schemes $\Spec(R)$ with closed point $\Spec(k)$ (in the category $\Sh/Y$) the natural map $\Hom_Y(\Spec(R), X) \to \Hom_Y(\Spec(k), X)$ is bijection [or with condition 3) below, just surjective].
2. it is locally finitely presented (in the presheaf theoretical sense).
3. it is a monomorphism.

Notes: a) Conditions 1) and 2) only are equivalent to the map being representable by "local isomorphisms of schemes" for example the map $X \to \mathbf{A}^1$ where $X$ is the affine line with the original double and the map just folds in the double point. However, these maps are 'no good' (i.e. they do not satisfy fpqc descent).

b) A scheme is a sheaf $X$ in the fpqc topology on $\Aff$ such that there exists a cover (in the canonical topology on $\Sh$) by affine schemes $(\Spec(R_i)\to X)_i$ with each map $\Spec(R_i)\to X$ satisfying the conditions above.

c) I haven't checked but I'm pretty sure this will work with the other natural topologies (fppf, étale, Zariski).

Comment: I think this is just equivalent to say $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is etale monomorphism

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are after, but when I started to look at Grothendieck-topologies I thought of being an open immersion as a topological property; somehow it should be possible to recover all open immersions from the topology, and if we changed the topology to the etalé site, the same method should give us the etalé maps as "open immersions".

Unfortunately, I doubt this is possible (it would be kind of nice if it were, so please correct me if I'm wrong). The reason why I was fooled to try, was probably due to the topological flavour of the term *open* immersion. But passing to the Grothendieck topology loses information about our model covering maps we started with. For instance, if {U_i -> U} is a covering, then a sheaf F would satisfy the sheaf condition also for the set {U_i -> U} U {A -> U}, the latter being an arbitrary morphism.

Instead I think it is more correct to think of the property of being an open immersion as something that we know what it is in our base category (affine schemes) and want to generalise to our new, larger category.

That said, we must look for the correct definition of open immersion in our base category. We want it to be something that is the "complement" of a closed immersion. Let F be a subfunctor of spec A. Pulling it back along  spec A/I -> spec A  should give us the zero scheme. Now define the complement of spec A/I as the most general subfunctor F of spec A satisfying this (i.e take the categorical limit). I've not done the details, but I suspect this gives the right concept and that a concrete description of what the subfunctor looks like would be as in exercise VI.6 in E-H. Extending it to representable morphisms of sheaves (in any reasonable topology) is now straight forward using pull-backs.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\Ring{\mathrm{Ring}}\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$Here is how you can define the notion of an Zarsiski-open subfunctor starting only with the Zariski topos $\mathcal Z$ of sheaves on $\Ring^\text{op}$ and its canonical internal ring object $\mathbb A$. The input data is $(\mathcal Z,\mathbb A)$, and nothing more.

In fact, allow me to describe a process which produces from any Grothendieck-topos $\mathcal E$ together with an internal (commutative) ring object $R$ in $\mathcal E$ a category of "schemes", such that when you plug $(\mathcal Z,\mathbb A)$ into it, it gives you the actual category of schemes. I will assume that the pair $(\mathcal E,R)$ satisfies a minimal amount of the axioms of synthetic differential geometry. In particular I will assume that $R$ is an internal field in the sense that the following is true. $$\mathcal E\models
\forall x:R. \, \neg (x=0)\to \exists y:R. x y=1$$
And I will assume that $0\neq 1$ in $R$. Both of these conditions are satisfied in the algebraic model $(\mathcal Z,\mathbb A$). As you can see, I use categorical logic.

**Step 1.** Single out the affine spaces: The internal ring object structure of $R$ gives each hom-set $\Hom_\mathcal E(X,R)$ the structure of a ring which we denote by $\mathcal O(X)$. Pulling back functions preserves the ring structure, and so we get a contravariant functor $\mathcal O:\mathcal E\to \Ring$. We say that an object $X$ in $\mathcal E$ is *affine* if and only if for every other object $Y$ it holds that $$\Hom_\mathcal E(Y,X)\to \Hom_{\Ring}(\mathcal OX,\mathcal OY)$$
is a bijection. In other words a morphism into $X$ is determined by and can be defined through how it pulls back the functions on $X$. This is a definition which doesn't make much sense for the standard models of SDG (because there $\mathcal O(X)$ has actually the structure of a $C^\infty$-ring), but in the case $(\mathcal Z,\mathbb A)$ it gives us precisely the representables inside $\mathcal Z$.

**Step 2.** Define the Zariski open subobjects of affine spaces. Fix an affine space $X$. For each function $f:X\to R$, let us declare the subobject $$D(f)=\{x:X|\neg f(x) = 0\}$$ of $X$ to be open. They are the basic open subobjects. Since we like the open subobjects of $X$ to form a lattice, let us also declare arbitrary joins (defined through colimits in $\mathcal E$) of such $D(f)$ to be open in $X$. Now we know what the open subspaces of affine spaces are.

**Lemma to step 2.** If $X$ is an affine space, then the poset of open subobjects of $X$ has not only arbitrary joins, but also finite meets. Furthermore, the join and meet operations in the lattice of opens agree with those of the surrounding category.

*Proof.* Let us check that the intersection $D(f)\wedge D(g)$ is $D(fg)$, where the multiplication of $f$ and $g$ is defined by postcomposition with the ring-structure multiplication map of $R$. The other statements follows automatically. To make this work, we actually need that $R$ is a field from the internal perspective. Because of that $D(f) = \{x:X|\, \ulcorner f(x)\text{ is invertible}\urcorner\}$ and since a product of elements in a ring is invertible if and only if both components are (and the proof of that algebra fact is intuitionistically valid), we see that indeed $D(f)\wedge D(g) = D(fg)$. $\square$

*Remark.* This is a definition which uses categorical logic. You can translate it into a categorical definition (which involves an equalizer) via the semantic described in Jacobs book, or in the case of a sheaf topos you can use the forcing semantic described in [Palmgren - Constructive sheaf semantics](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Ehhalvors/teaching/phi323_f2009/palmgren.pdf) to translate it in a concrete situation. What you will find out (after translation) is that in the case $(\mathcal Z,\mathbb A)$ and for an affine scheme $\Spec A$ the subobject $D(f)$ is precisely $\Spec A[1/f]\to \Spec A$. If $I$ is an ideal in $A$ and you form the join $\bigvee_{f\in I} D(f)$ in $\mathcal Z$, then you will see that the resulting subobject is precisely the subobject $D(I)$ associated to $I$ as it is described in Demazure & Gabriel's book.

**Step 3.** Define a topology on arbitrary objects. Given any object $Y$ in $\mathcal Z$, we equip it with the strongest topology such that all maps from affine spaces into $Y$ stay continuous. This means that a subobject $U$ is open in $Y$ if and only if for every affine space $X$ and every morphism $\phi:X\to Y$ the preimage $\phi^{-1}U$ (defined through a pullback) is open in $X$.

**Lemma to step 3.** We need of course check that the new definition doesn't introduce any new open subobjects on affine spaces. It does not.

*Proof.* Assume $U$ is a subobject of an affine space $X$ such that the pullback to every other affine space is open. Then in particular $id_X^{-1}U = U$ is open in $X$, and we see that $U$ is already open in $X$. Conversely take any st-indexed join $\bigvee_iD(f_i)$ of basic open subobjects $D(f_i)$ in $X$, and let $\phi:Y\to X$ be a test map from an affine space. Then $$\phi^{-1}(\bigvee_iD(f_i)) = \bigvee_i \phi^{-1}D(f_i)= \bigvee_i D(f_i\circ \phi) $$
for categorical reasons, and we see that the pullback is open in $Y$. $\square$

**Final step.** Define the category of schemes. A scheme is an object $X$ which can be covered by some collection of affine open subobjects $U_i$. Here covered means that $\bigvee_iU_i=X$. Alternatively the induced map $\sqcup_i U_i \to X$ is an epimorphism in $\mathcal E$.

If you apply that process to the stating data $(\mathcal Z, \mathbb A)$, then you get the category of schemes. Crucially you need not know what the representables are or what the defining site of $\mathcal Z$ is, you only need the internal line $\mathbb A$.

**Edit.** Here are some texts which explain the translation of internal statements in categorical logic to external meaningful statements.

- The link above is the paper [*Constructive Sheaf Semantics* by Erik Palmgreen](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Ehhalvors/teaching/phi323_f2009/palmgren.pdf). It has a nice list of translation rules on the fourth page, and I always use it in praxis.
- There are two texts by Andrew Pitts which are really beginner friendly, concise and clear. They are called *Categorical Logic* and *Notes on Categorical Logic* and can be found online.
- The ultimate reference is the first half of Bart Jacobs' book *Categorical Logic and Type Theory*.

I think this should be enough, but if this post happend to get you interested in categorical logic, feel free to text me. I have collected a huge number of lecture notes and books, which I am happy to share. :)

Even though the forcing semantic of categorical logic is site dependent, the standard semantic (as explained e.g. in Jacobs' book) is not. It depends only on the category and its limits and colimits. The external statement one gets through the forcing semantic is always equivalent to the translation one gets through the categorical semantic, even though they might look different. In that sense the forcing semantic is a useful tool, when a defining site is available, but the justification for categorical logic comes from the categorical semantic. I am just adding this so that no one thinks that I am sneaking in a site-dependency through the forcing semantic!

Comment: I know that this is a very old question, but the question comes up when you search online, and I think my answer is useful.

Comment: "the forcing semantic described here " <--- this link looks very unstable, and if the link rots there's very little to go on to hunt for a replacement. Can you give a bit more detail in-text and/or give a more stable source? (for instance to published work...)

Comment: @David Roberts Yes, of course. The paper is published, but I can add the name of some recourses at the end, which explain the forcing semantic nicely.

Comment: thanks, that helps!

Comment: [DOI](https://doi-org.ezproxy.tcu.edu/10.1002/malq.19970430304 "Palmgren - Constructive sheaf semantics") for Palmgren - Constructive sheaf semantics.